# mjml enable horizontal scroll for table, add overflow to mjml

Tags: html, css, email, email-templates, mjml

I am using `mjml` to create email template that contains table. And the header names are long and the table gets too large horizontally. I wanted to make it horizontally scrollable within the blue container, But I was unable to do so.

[image]

How can I make this scrollable?

**[Here](https://mjml.io/try-it-live/CGV2WNeb7) is the live code for the mjml**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add css classes using `<mj-style>`

```
<mjml>
  <mj-head>
    <mj-style>
      .overflow-scroll { overflow: scroll; }
    </mj-style>
  </mj-head>
  ...
```

And add the class to the containing `<mj-column>`

```
  <mj-column width="555px" background-color="#f4f4f9" border-radius="10px" padding-bottom="10px" css-class="overflow-scroll">
    <mj-table cellpadding="6px">
      <body>
```

[Here](https://mjml.io/try-it-live/jsr3FrZgr) is the fixed source

Comment: Overflow has zero support in Outlook. I think your code should take into account all email clients have have fallbacks. https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=overflow